# Why does hibernate remove data from association table?

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, mapping

I have following relation in my program:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student extends Person {
    private Map<Document, DocumentInfo> documents =
       new HashMap<Document, DocumentInfo>();
    ...
    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "student_documents",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "document_info"))
    @MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "document")
    public Map<Document, DocumentInfo> getDocuments() {
        return documents;
    }
    ...
}
```

When I save student with his documents information all seems good..
When I read him from database all seems good too, but when I try to read it one more time I have NullPointerException. I did some research and found that during the first invocation of `student.getDocuments()` hibernate deletes records from table `student_documents`:

```
Hibernate: select document0_.id as id2_0_, document0_.title as title2_0_ from document document0_ where document0_.id=?
Hibernate: select document0_.id as id2_0_, document0_.title as title2_0_ from document document0_ where document0_.id=?
Hibernate: delete from student_documents where student=?
```

What I've done wrong?
Thanks

my test code looks like:

```
    Student student = new Student();
    student.setFirstName("123");
    studentService.add(student);
    Student student2 = studentService.read(student.getId());
    assertFalse(student2.getDocuments().size() == 0); // here it all occurs
```

service method:

```
public Student add(Student student) {
    for (Document document : documentRepository.findAll()) {
        DocumentInfo documentInfo = new DocumentInfo(false, "");
        documentInfoRepository.save(documentInfo);
        student.getDocuments().put(document, documentInfo);
    }
    return studentRepository.save(student);
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that you commit to hibernate empty `documents` for the first time?

Comment: One imagines you're clearing the map or assigning null/an empty map to it somewhere that the entity is managed.  When you make changes on an entity, they go to the database.  It is not like JDBC where things don't get changed unless you explicitly commit an update/delete.

Comment: No, I initialize map before writing to database. I write there entries and then I can see records from the database gui manager. Then, when I just only invoke getDocuments() (not clearing the map or do something else) i see in log that hibernate clearing my association table

Comment: @Affe excuse, I added my code to the first message

Comment: what does `read` do?  How are you managing session lifecycle and transaction boundaries?

Comment: The private variable instantiation is causing your problem.  Don't instantiate the Map.  Let Hibernate manage it.  What's happening is when it goes to create a new Entity from a record it creates a new object and since the private variable is instantiated it causes the bound object to delete it's records.  If you remove the instantiation that should stop.

Comment: @Joe I left only `private Map<Document, DocumentInfo> documents;` but it doesn't work normally whatever

Comment: @Affe service `read` method just invokes Spring Data Jpa repository method `findOne`. I'm working with transactions over spring annotation `@Transactional` on service methods

Comment: Maybe it's a problem on the other side of my association? should relation of this type be bidirectional?

Comment: @vasileusky It could have to do with the other side of the relation too.  If you're setting it up like this I think it is expecting it to be bidirectional.  Try to fetch the record eagerly too.  Something tells me the lazy relationship is causing this.

Comment: @Joe yes! it doesn't delete records when fetch type is eager. but what does it mean and what should I do if I don't want to load all this information early?

Comment: @vasileusky unfortunately I've run into this problem before and I never actually found a way around it without refactoring.  I would be interested if someone else could chime in with why this occurs.  I do know by fetching eager the join is made properly but when it is lazy hibernate has ids, but since the select statements don't return what's needed hibernate decides to delete the ids.  Does this happen to be a fresh database though?

Comment: Most interesting is that the collection is loaded properly even if fetch type is set to lazy. But only for the first time.. because immediately after the loading table is clearing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I just found the issue. Can't check it now in my old project, but it's very similar to problems related to [this hibernate bug](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-7971).